# Is Spring IoC in Spring framework a service locator pattern?

Tags: java, spring

The service locator pattern is known as an anti-pattern, and the process of injecting Bean in Spring and the structure of using it seem very similar.
I want to know what the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference may seem slight,

- With the `ServiceLocator`, the class is still responsible for creating its dependencies. It just uses the service locator to do it.
- With DI used in IoC, the class is given its dependencies. It neither knows, nor cares where they come from.

One important result of this is that the DI example is much easier to unit test

1. Because you can pass it mock implementations of its dependent objects.
2. You have freedom to combine the two and, inject the service locator (or a factory), if you wanted.

References :
 - https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think what the respondent said was that the spring-framework is DI.
My question is to register Component and ask because I think the IoC (Bean Manager) is similar to the 'Service Locator'.

Comment: IoC bean manager is container managed and ```serviceLocator``` is application managed.
In case of , ```serviceLocator``` it has been asked by each bean to get an instance and in case of ```DI``` it's searched by proxy spring objects and wired to the actual class.
IoC is combination of ```serviceLocator``` + ```proxy``` + ```listeners over metadata``` to implement DI.

Answer (score 0):

> Service Locator pattern is an implementations of Inversion of Control
>   concept.

Basic idea behind **service locator design pattern** is to have an object that knows how to get hold of all of the services that an application might need.

It encapsulate the processes involved in obtaining a service with an abstraction layer via a central registry known as *service locator*.

[image]

Whenever a request lands to service locator it returns the information necessary to perform a certain task.

> **IOC is a principle and a lot of design patterns are derived out of it.**

[image]